# How do you stop an out of control wscript command?

Tags: wsh

How do you stop an out of control wscript command? Do you press CTRL+C ? Is there a way to stop it?

Comment: Somebody out there doesn't like my wsh questions.

Comment: You have over 10k rep you think by now you'd know how to properly structure a question on [so]. But just in case here’s a page you should have read [ask] and let’s not forget the all important [mcve].

Comment: @Lankymart I can't make a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.  It's a script that runs from `wsh somescript.js` and if it was running to press some keys and say a window popped up and the rest of the steps in the script randomly ran on some other window...then there should be some sort of keyboard shortcut to stop it I'd think.  Besides, my question isn't so bad, this question got through: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512827/how-to-stop-wscript-exe?rq=1 and it isn't even directly asking about a wsh script, it's asking about how to stop a process started by a wsh script.

Comment: That’s a historical question, don’t go basing your question quality off that the standards changed years ago.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Stop Wscript Exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512827/how-to-stop-wscript-exe)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Provided the only task running in `wscript` is the one you're running you could assign a desktop shortcut to a hotkey so that it runs `TASKKILL /F /IM wscript.exe` and all wscript processes will be killed / stopped when you press the assigned hotkey.